# Expansion of the falling factorial

Tags: combinatorics, pochhammer-symbol

Let $(x)_n=x(x-1)\ldots (x-(n-1))$ be the falling factorial.

For  small $n$ I have found
$$
(xy)_1=(x)_1 (y)_1,\\
(xy)_2=x (x)_1 (y)_2+(x)_2 (y)_1,\\
(xy)_3=x^2 (x)_1 (y)_3+3 x (x)_2(y)_2+(x)_3(y)_1
$$
Is there any  general formula for the expansion $(xy)_n$ in terms of $(x)_i, (y)_i$?
I hope must be something likes to 
$$
(xy)_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x^{n-i} (x)_i (y)_{n+1-i},
$$
for some sequence $\alpha_i$.
I think it is well-known result.